# Windows 10: use 2 microphones without mixing inputs

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, audio-recording, microphone

I need to use 2 microphones on a laptop (the integrated one and one that can be plugged with the classic jack), so that I can distinguish who is talking based on the microphone where he's talking. So I cannot use audio mixers, but I need to keep separated the two inputs.

It's possible to do that? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Lync, Jabber, Skype or any other conferencing system in which you want to use more than one microphone, this tutorial is for you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQHP1PZBPvc

1.Download Virtual Audio Cable from this page (most likely you want the 64 bit version)

2.Install Virtual Audio Cable – do NOT touch the software after the install

3.Go to your Windows RECORDING DEVICES – do NOT touch your PLAYBACK DEVICES

4.Double click on each Microphone you want to use, click the SOUNDS TAB, click LISTEN TO THIS DEVICE and set the drop down to LINE 1 VIRTUAL AUDIO CABLE

5.In  RECORDING DEVICES, right click on LINE 1 VIRTUAL AUDIO CABLE and set it to DEFAULT

Comment: But, for what I've understood, with this software the 2 microphones inputs are merged. Instead I want to keep them separated.